# NodeJS Json Return id only?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Here's the NodeJS code I'm using to create a customer in my MySql database;

```
const customer = new Customer({
    email: req.body.email,
    name: req.body.name,
    active: req.body.active
  });

  Customer.create(customer, (err, data) => {
    if (err)
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Customer."
      });
    else res.send(data);
  });
};
```

Heres' the model;

```
const Customer = function(customer) {
  this.email = customer.email;
  this.name = customer.name;
  this.active = customer.active;
};

Customer.create = (newCustomer, result) => {
  sql.query("INSERT INTO customers SET ?", newCustomer, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: ", err);
      result(err, null);
      return;
    }

    console.log("created customer: ", { id: res.insertId, ...newCustomer });
    result(null, { id: res.insertId, ...newCustomer });
  });
};
```

And here's what I'm getting in return;

```
{"id":8,"email":"harry@gmail.com","name":"harry","active":1}
```

How can I get it to return just the id as a plain integer instead of the entire JSON string?

Comment: If you only want `8` as output you can return with `res.send(data.id);` instead of `res.send(data);`

Comment: I got this error; RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: 16

Comment: the return data must be a string so try `res.send(data.id.toString())`

Comment: Thanks that worked! If you put it as an answer can choose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the specific property from the object. e.g. id, access it as `data.id` and `id` is an number which will be treated as status code in express so `toString()` is needed to convert it to string

The response should be:

```js
res.send(data.id.toString())
```